# How to use middleware on routes in laravel?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I need to implement a little functionality for my application.
I have a form for editing and only admin must have access to it.
I can't figure out how to arrange the routes correctly, because I get
**"The site has redirected too many times."**

middleware:

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = new User();
        if ($user->role_id !==1) {

            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('/product', 'IndexController@store');
Route::get('/product', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('/product/create', 'IndexController@create');
Route::put('/product/{product}', 'IndexController@update');
Route::get('/product/{product}/edit', 'IndexController@edit')->middleware('admin');
```

This route should be available only for admin 
`'/product/{product}/edit'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are newing up a user: `$user = new User();`. You probably want your authenticated user: `$user = auth()->user()`

Comment: I agree, it's really worth adding authentication checks, but I also need to check if the user has a role 1 
Now my check looks like this `if (Auth::check() && $user->role_id !==1)` If the user is admin, it works `return redirect('/')`. It turns out the opposite, the admin does not have access to the form, and the user and the guest have access. I think that my problem is in the routes, but I do not understand how to arrange it correctly.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to add in authentication checks. I'm saying you need to use your authenticated user: `$user = auth()->user()` or `$user = $request->user()`

Comment: This does not work `$user = auth()->user(); dd($user)`  returns null. I'm confused even more. Why is that? I have not previously worked with middleware, so I ask for help.

Comment: You are probably not authenticated. Change your route so that it is behind authenticated middleware too: `Route::get('/product/{product}/edit', 'IndexController@edit')->middleware(['auth','admin']);`. I'm assuming you have to login to your application using a username/password combo?

Comment: I did as you say. I logged in as Admin, but I still get null. How would you write a check? Table users has column role_id. Admin has role_id 1

Comment: If you add the auth middleware to your route as well the user should never be null. You should instead be redirected to your login endpoint by the auth middleware. In addition it would be helpful to know how you configured this middleware in Kernel.php

Comment: in Kernel. php `protected $middleware = [\App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ]; protected $routeMiddleware = ['admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have just solved this problem without using middleware.

Comment: Remove the middleware from `protected $middleware`. That is not the correct place for that middleware.